# Java: Make an animation/video from frames

Tags: java, video, animation, gif, avi

Howdy!  For a research project (in Java), I've got to find some way to save an animation of a graph into  some file format.  Now I've already got the program working fine drawing each frame.  The problem is, short of learning the whole GIF or AVI file format, I have no idea how to assemble the frames programmatically into some sort of animation or video file.  File formats don't really matter--input or output.  I just need some way to put the frames together and save!

Right now I'm thinking the easiest format would be either animated GIF or AVI.  Again, though, it really doesn't matter so long as it works.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They might not be the best options, but I just thought of these:

- You might be able to use some QuickTime APIs. I know they're used fairly often for webcam input, and that they can also generate video.
- You could also generate each frame and then assemble them with [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) -- it'll let you save graphics into pretty much any video format.