# How to convert .gif images into an .avi video using java?

Tags: java, video

Given a bunch of images `.gif` which I retrieve from mySQL, I need to convert all of them into an `.avi` video. So I have `img1.gif,img2.gif....,imgn.gif`, in that order in need to animate the video. What API/Library should I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out a previous question here on stackoverflow with a great answer: [Java: How do I create a movie from an array of images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856757/java-how-do-i-create-a-movie-from-an-array-of-images) and here: [Java: Make an animation/video from frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286474/java-make-an-animation-video-from-frames) found them on a quick google of the topic